# Include pdf-graphic without including the whole pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf

I have drawn a lattice in latex with tikz, successfully compiled it to a pdf and been able to include it in my document. However, the whole PDF (i.e. A4 page) is included and I only want to include the lattice I have drawn.

Is it possible to automatically only include that lattice and not all the "blank space" around it? (I know "crop" is an option, but if I want to change the lattice so that it changes size, it will be a bother to update the crop coordinates all the time.)

Comment: In your original TikZ drawing, use `standalone` document class and it will crop the picture automatically. You can search this site for lots of examples.

Comment: Thanks! That is an answer to my question. Please post it (for points) and so that this thread can get an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your original TikZ drawing, use [`standalone`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/standalone) document class or [`preview`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/preview) and the picture will be cropped automatically.

Then you can include the resulting pdf to your main file.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use the solution by percusse, you can use [pdfcrop](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop). It's a perl script that removes all white borders of a pdf. Works with multiple pages too.